# Error in making a leveling system discord.py

Tags: python, mongodb, discord, discord.py, pymongo

I am trying to make a leveling system in my discord.py bot.
I am using MongoDB atlas as a database.

Here is my code.

```
import os
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient

class Levelling(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Levelling is Ready')

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, ctx):


        cluster = pymongo.MongoClient('Link here')
        db = cluster["levels"]
        collection = db["Level"]

        author_id = ctx.author.id
        guild_id = ctx.guild.id
        user_id = {'_id': author_id}


        if ctx.author == bot.user: ### Checks if it is a bot command (I Think so)
            return

        if ctx.author.bot: ### Avoids bots from Leveling up. (I Think so)
            return

        if collection.count_documents({} == 0):
            user_info = {'id': author_id, 'GuildId': guild_id, 'Level': 1, 'XP': 0}
            collection.insert_one(user_info)

        await ctx.send('user has been Logged in.')
```

My error:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/runner/Shiny-disc-bot/levelling.py", line 30, in on_message
    if ctx.author == bot.user:
NameError: name 'bot' is not defined
```

Basically, it says bot is not defined. But i have defined it in my main.py.

My main.py:

```
#------importing packages


import keep_alive
import os
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='-')
bot.remove_command('help')
my_token = os.environ['Token']






#------When bot is online


@bot.event
async def on_ready():


  #status
  #playing game status


  await bot.change_presence(activity = discord.Game(name = f'On {len(bot.guilds)} Servers | -help'))

  print('Bot is Ready')


initial_extensions = ['fun', 'help', 'math1', 'mod', 'levelling']

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for extension in initial_extensions:
        bot.load_extension(extension)



#ping latency....
@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'Pong\n{round(bot.latency * 1000)}ms')

  

#------Running the bot
keep_alive.keep_alive()
bot.run(my_token)
```

If you have any tutorials on how to make a leveling system with mongodb, please share them to me.

I am following
[This Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y25K_gD2_as)

Comment: `if ctx.author == bot.user:` -> it should be `self.bot.user`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's failing to connect to the database.

And you can leave `if ctx.author == bot.user:` out, this checks if the author is the bot itself. `if ctx.author.bot` is enough.

Answer (score -1):

Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
await coro(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/runner/Shiny-disc-bot/levelling.py", line 36, in on_message
if collection.count_documents({} == 0):
File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 1785, in count_documents
return self.__database.client._retryable_read(
File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1460, in _retryable_read
server = self._select_server(
File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1278, in _select_server
server = topology.select_server(server_selector)
File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 241, in select_server
return random.choice(self.select_servers(selector,
File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 199, in select_servers
server_descriptions = self._select_servers_loop(
File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 215, in _select_servers_loop
raise ServerSelectionTimeoutError(
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: cluster0.h9fmz.mongodb.net:27017: [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname, Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 60cb604579f655526c4e0ac1, topology_type: Single, servers: [<ServerDescription ('cluster0.h9fmz.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('cluster0.h9fmz.mongodb.net:27017: [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname')>]>

This is the error i get after doing self.bot.user

Comment: This is not even remotely related with your original question, feel free to ask a new one.